# How to open modal in vue

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-modal, vuejs3

Currently, I'm making a modal in vue3

I would like to use the modal component provided by bootstrap.

I try to make the modal window pop up when I press the delete comment button.

Therefore, when the value of delete_show becomes true, the conditions were set so that the modal would appear.

However, modals do not appear.

Modal-related codes and component-related codes are located together in one component.

What should I do to make the modal appear?

```js
<template>
  <div
    class="modal"
    tabindex="-1"
    v-if="delete_show == true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">
            댓글 삭제
          </h5>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn-close"
            data-bs-dismiss="modal"
            aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>댓글을 삭제하시겠습니까?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-secondary"
            data-bs-dismiss="modal">
            취소
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            @click="commentDelete"
            class="btn btn-primary">
            삭제
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="commentListWrapper">
      <ul class="commentBoxWrapper">
        <li class="comments">
          <div class="commentArea">
            <div class="commentAreaTop">
              <div class="commentUser">
                {{ userComment.userId }}
              </div>
              <div class="commentRating">
                {{ userComment.starRate }}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div
              class="commentText"
              v-if="edit">
              {{ userComment.comment }}
            </div>
            <div
              v-else
              class="commentFixArea">
              <textarea
                class="commentFixBox"
                v-model="userComment.comment"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div
              v-if=" userComment.userId === this.$store.state.loginService.UserInfoObj.id && edit"
              class="commentMethods">
              <div class="commentFix">
                <span @click="changeEdit">수정</span>
              </div>
              <div class="commentDelete">
                <span @click="changeModalStatus">삭제</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div
              class="editButton"
              v-else-if="!edit">
              <button
                type="button"
                @click="commentFix"
                class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                저장
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>  
</template>
```

Comment: where do you trigger your modal? For the future, please always keep your code to the minimum! Thank You!

Comment: The name of this component is CommentEnter, and the CommentEnter component is a subcomponent of CommentBox. And this commentbox is a component of a router called Detailed.

Comment: Please add all the required code or better create codesandbox so the solution can be provided at ease.

Comment: Maybe inspect the DOM and see if the modal is there. You use v-if which will toggle the modal markup on/off (vs v-show) so you should be able to inspect and if the markup for the modal is present then it's probably a CSS issue (z-index or something else)

Comment: I solved the problem by putting the modal-show in the class because I didn't use the bootstrap-vue package, but bootstrap css.